# получить UI элемент через скрипт

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Начну из далека.
В Unity опыта не имею совсем, поэтому могу формулировать не очень ясно.
Создал класс для всех Объектов в игре, с которыми могу взаимодействовать (допустим название NPC).
Хочу чтобы при OnTriggerEnter2D каждый раз наверху экрана выводился текст о том, что я могу взаимодействовать с объектом, но не могу понять, как мне обратиться к этому объекту. 
Да, можно создать [SerializedField], но не хочется к каждому объекту добавлять этот UI элемент.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я прекрасно понимаю, что можно это сделать вот и каждый раз к каждому NPC перетаскивать этот текст. Просто думал что есть решение более элегантное в этом плане, чтобы этот текст был там определён по умолчанию, так сказать.

Comment: создайте класс с вашим UI и почитайте про ссылочные типы данных

Comment: @AntonNikolaev то есть мне нужно ссылаться на этот класс внутри моего класса  NPC чтобы методы оттуда работали ? Просто, если буду даже создавать скрипт, мне же в нём всё равно надо будет ссылаться на этот UI элемент.